# Post method is not working while migrating one maching to other machine

Tags: java, tomcat, restful-url

After migrating restfull application from one machine another machine we are able to acess only GET type methods but we are unable to access POST type methods. I am using Tomcat 6.0.36.Please help on this.
Please find the code which I am using.

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.ResponseObject;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.Clients.MobileAPIClient;

@Path("/MobileAppFNOLAPI")
public class MobileAppFNOLAPI {


@GET
@Path("/getClaims")
public JSONObject getClaims(
    @QueryParam("input") String input) {

    String getClaims = null;

    JSONObject jsonObject = null;

    System.out.println("inside getClaims()"+input);

    MobileAPIClient mobileAPIClient = new MobileAPIClient();
    try {

        getClaims = mobileAPIClient.callPersonalAPI().getClaims(input);

        System.out.println(getClaims);

        jsonObject = new JSONObject(getClaims);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonObject;

}


@GET
@Path("/getClaimStatus")
public JSONObject getClaimStatus(
    @QueryParam("input") String input) {

    System.out.println("inside getClaimStatus()"+input);

    String claimStatus = null;

    JSONObject jsonObject = null;

    // Write the business Logic and return the output finally

    MobileAPIClient mobileAPIClient = new MobileAPIClient();
    try {
        claimStatus = mobileAPIClient.callPersonalAPI().getClaimStatus(input);
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(claimStatus);
        System.out.println(claimStatus);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return jsonObject;

}


@POST
@Path("/savePortalClaim/{xmlInput}")

        public JSONObject savePortalClaim (@PathParam("xmlInput") String xmlInput) {
    String saveClaimStatus = null;
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    System.out.println("inside savePortalClaim() "+xmlInput);

    MobileAPIClient mobileAPIClient = new MobileAPIClient();
    try {
         saveClaimStatus = mobileAPIClient.callPersonalAPI().savePortalClaim(xmlInput);
         jsonObject = new JSONObject(saveClaimStatus);
         System.out.println(saveClaimStatus);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Write the business Logic and return the output finally
    return jsonObject;
}
@GET
@Path("/doesPolicyExists")
public JSONObject doesPolicyExists(@QueryParam("policyNumber") String policyNumber,@QueryParam("password") String password) {

System.out.println("inside doesPolicyExists()"+policyNumber);
System.out.println("inside doesPolicyExists()"+password);

//String policyNumber = null
JSONObject jsonObject = null;

// Write the business Logic and return the output finally

MobileAPIClient mobileAPIClient = new MobileAPIClient();
try {
    System.out.println("startinggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg");
   String  policyResult = mobileAPIClient.callPersonalAPI().doesPolicyExists(policyNumber, password);
    System.out.println("policyResult--------------------------->"+policyResult); 
    jsonObject = new JSONObject(policyResult);

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}


return jsonObject;

}}
```

Comment: Please provide more information. What implementation of `REST` you are using, what is your machine, what is the code and all other relevent information

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have posted the code. And I am using window 7 machine.

Answer (score 0):

- It could be that, on one machine you have got HTTP VERB POST enabled but not on the machine that is not working.
- Worth checking the TOMCAT web server configuration between the machines.

Comment: in web.xml I have used following code <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Ressources REST</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>      
      <role-name>*</role-name> 
    </auth-constraint>  
  </security-constraint>